# Sync folder from shared CentOS server to VPS CentOS server

Tags: centos, synchronization

I have a doc management app on shared CentOS server and docs from all clients/users are saved in one folder(not in public_html).

I backed all docs to a VPS box but now would like just to sync difference every hour or so from shared CentOS box to VPS.

How can I do that?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

1. VPS has OpenSSH installed
2. You have configured password-less public key access to VPS from CentOS

On the CentOS system, create a crontab entry as root, similar to this:

`0 * * * * rsync -avz -e ssh /path/to/docs vpsuser@vps:/destination/path`

Comment: This works Ok. I had some issues with passwordless public key access to VPS but this works. Thank you. I have a subquestion. How can i sync deleted files on shared CentOS with VPS?

Comment: Are you wanting to remove files on the VPS that were removed from CentOS, or remove the files from CentOS *after* they are transferred to the VPS?